# How to alter a table to add a default value on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use ms sql 2008 I have problem to add a default value to a column on a specific table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CmsAuthors
ALTER COLUMN IsContentAuthorPublished
  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CmsAuthors_IsContentAuthorPublished DEFAULT 0
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CmsAuthors
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CmsAuthors_IsContentAuthorPublished  
DEFAULT 0 FOR IsContentAuthorPublished
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CmsAuthors
    ALTER COLUMN IsContentAuthorPublished
     ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CmsAuthors_IsContentAuthorPublished DEFAULT 0
 for <Column Name>
```